# syntax error, finally block is not recognized

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Get syntax error, unexpected `'{'`. When I delete, finally block it works. that is a GET method of RESTful service.

```
Route::resource('braining/firmware', 'Braining\FirmwareController',
                    ['only' => ['index']]);
```

Controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Braining;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class FirmwareController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        try {
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
        }
        finally {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Most probably you're using PHP 5.4 or lower. The `finally` block of try-catch was added in PHP 5.5.

Comment: Yes it is a problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrade PHP to version `5.5` and the problem will go away.

> In PHP 5.5 and later, a finally block may also be specified after or
>   instead of catch blocks. Code within the finally block will always be
>   executed after the try and catch blocks, regardless of whether an
>   exception has been thrown, and before normal execution resumes.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php#language.exceptions.finally

Answer (score 4):

You must be using PHP 5.4 or lower which does not have the finally implemented yet. Either remove it or upgrade the PHP to 5.5