# How to configure/enable php-phantomjs on shared hosting server

Tags: laravel-5, phantomjs, php-phantomjs

I am using PHP-Phantomjs http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/ to capture the content of my website, tools I am using Laravel v5.0 and PHP-Phantomjs v4.0 it is working perfect on my local MAC machine but the problem is.

I have uploaded files manually as I had to do always to the server and there is no difference in files, but when I try to generate image following error occurs.

```
FatalErrorException in ContainerBuilder.php line 419:
syntax error, unexpected 'finally' (T_STRING), expecting catch (T_CATCH)
```

I think the **phantomJS exec** file I have uploaded is not compatible, or is there something else I have to do to enable the phantomJS on GoDaddy server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [syntax error, finally block is not recognized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29843233/syntax-error-finally-block-is-not-recognized)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because, `finally` block of `try-catch` was added in `PHP 5.5`. So the reason it wont't work, you have older version of PHP on your production server.